# Cannot write file xml output form a procedure - ORA-06512: a "SYS.UTL_FILE"

Tags: oracle, plsql, utl-file

in our production environment we use a procedure that read from our DB Oracle 12c and write about 2000 files xml in output on the filesystem, all in the same directory.

Now we have a problem: after that 1400 files are already writed, the procedure fails with error:

```
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
```

There is enough space on the filesystem to write the files and i have already checked the permissions.

In the procedure we call:

```
xdb.dbms_xslprocessor.clob2file(xml_document,R_FILE_FOLDER,substr(xml_file_name,0,instr(xml_file_name,'.',-1)-1)||'.unc',nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8'));
```

Thank you

Comment: Maybe the procedure generates an invalid filename for the 1401st file?

Comment: Can you still manually add files to the filesystem? Just wondering if you're hitting an inode limit or something.

Comment: The filename have this format:  date_id_timestamp.xml where date is YYYYMMDD, id is a 5 number digit.

Comment: Maybe disc is getting full?

Comment: Might the 1401st file already exists and you don't have permission to overwrite it?

Comment: Problem solved: it was a parallel execution issue. Our database is composed of 2 nodes and one of them had a fault. The execution starts with the first node and run fine but when the second thread use the other node the procedure fails. It was hard to find because we use a NAS and the check on the disk were done on the first node.